# Longest Repeating Substring in Java

Tags: java, substring

We were given instructions to write that accepts a string as input
and computes and prints the longest substring displayed two
times without overlap (see 5th example for overlap). If there are more
from one of such sub-strings, the program displays the first one it finds as well the number of characters in the substring. If there is no substring that appears 2 times, then the program will not print anything. Examples that we were given on how the output should look like:

1st Example

```
Give a string: again and again
Longest substring: again
Longest substring size: 5
```

2nd Example

```
Give a string: seven saints and seven dinners
Longest substring: seven
Longest substring size: 6
Note: The answer completes the space and is 6 characters.
```

3rd Example

```
Give a string: Seven saints and seven sinners
Longest substring: even s
Longest substring size: 6
```

4th Example
Give a string: Mary had a little lamb
Longest substring: l
Longest substring size: 2

5th Example
Give a string: racecaracecar
Longest substring: raceca
Longest substring size: 6

My code up to now is the following, and doesn't work, in that the output screen is just empty, and when I tried to print the Array List, it just listed [null]. What is wrong with it and how can it be made to work?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class substring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = args[0];
        ArrayList<String> longestSubstring=new ArrayList<String>();
        String substring;
        
        for (int firstcharacter=0; firstcharacter<string.length()-1; firstcharacter++) {
            for(int secondcharacter=firstcharacter+1; secondcharacter<string.length()-1; secondcharacter++) {
            substring=string.substring(firstcharacter,secondcharacter);
            
            for (int i=substring.length()+1; i<string.length()-1; i++) {
                String firsttwo=String.valueOf(string.charAt(i)+string.charAt(i+1));
                if (substring==firsttwo) {
                    longestSubstring.add(substring);
                }
            }
                    
            }
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < longestSubstring.size(); i++) {   
            System.out.print(longestSubstring.get(i));
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: what does "non-repeating" means here ? I don't get it

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What is the output of your code for each of the example inputs? At first glance I see you are comparing strings with `==` instead of `equals()`, but without further information I can't tell if that's the only problem with your code.

Comment: @azro Perhaps "non-overlapping"? Though that would be a weird way to word it.

Comment: In the first example, why isn't `again and ` the longest non-repeating string?  It doesn't repeat, and it's longer than just "again".

Comment: hey, I made some edits, I hope it makes the question more clear

Comment: To everybody who is understandably confused: The examples make complete sense if the title was "Longest __repeating__ string". As in, it's `again` because `again` (the string) shows up more than once. Hence why for e.g. racecaracecar it's raceca, that's the longest string for which two substrings exist equal to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=secondcharacter+1; i<string.length()-1; i++) {
                    String firsttwo=String.valueOf(string.charAt(i)+string.charAt(i+1));
                    System.out.println("2 chars: "+firsttwo+", matching: "+substring);
                    if (substring.equals(firsttwo)) {
                        System.out.println(substring);
                        longestSubstring.add(substring);
                    }
                }
```

try using print statements to debug your code. When i tried the following it gave me this output:

```
2 chars: 200, matching: ra
2 chars: 200, matching: ra
2 chars: 196, matching: ra
2 chars: 211, matching: ra
2 chars: 146, matching: ra
2 chars: 129, matching: ra
2 chars: 207, matching: ra
2 chars: 210, matching: ra
2 chars: 132, matching: ra
2 chars: 146, matching: ra
2 chars: 211, matching: ra
2 chars: 196, matching: ra
2 chars: 200, matching: ra
2 chars: 200, matching: ra
```

this means that you are matching ascii characters (your firsttwo) against a substring

Comment: Thank you very much! When I run with argument of  ''again and again'',  the output is the following, which I don't really understand what it gives                                              2 chars: 202, matching: a
2 chars: 215, matching: a
2 chars: 215, matching: ag
2 chars: 215, matching: g

Comment: The issue would be with how you are getting your firsttwo string. Using the substring() should resolve it. the charAt() method returns a char and because you are not explicitly indicating it is a string, the use of + operator indicates that it should be treated as ascii not a concatenate.

Comment: however, the simplest thing you could do, is ```string.charAt(i)+""+string.charAt(i+1)```